# How to list sub directory first and then parent directory in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, command

How to list subdirectory first and then parent directory in command prompt. Child to parent traverse instead of Parent to child

Lets, say I've folder 'Income' and sub folder 'Tax', 'Tax' contains sub Folder 'Report' and need list as deepest folder first

D:/Income/Tax/Report
D:/Income/Tax/
D:/Income/

Used **dir /A:D/S/B/O:-D** command still it list as Parent to Child

Comment: Does piping that to `| sort /R` help?  `dir /A:D/S/B/O:-D | sort /R`.

Comment: The sort option `/O` of `dir` works on a per-directory basis, so you need some post-sorting…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piping that command to reverse sort seems to help?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1348]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>d:

D:\>dir /A:D/S/B/O:-D | sort /R
// ... removed extra
D:\preload\RM_Reserve\system.sav\FactoryUpdate\FU_6_277229_20171201_200A1
D:\preload\RM_Reserve\system.sav\FactoryUpdate\FU_6_260181_20170916_100A1
D:\preload\RM_Reserve\system.sav\FactoryUpdate
D:\preload\RM_Reserve\system.sav
D:\preload\RM_Reserve\SWSetup\sw_ver
D:\preload\RM_Reserve\SWSetup
D:\preload\RM_Reserve
D:\preload\RM_PATCH
D:\preload\FactoryUpdate\UserDLSoftpaq
D:\preload\FactoryUpdate
D:\preload
D:\Income\Tax\Reports         // Listed here
D:\Income\Tax
D:\Income
D:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\zh-tw
D:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\zh-hk
D:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\zh-cn
D:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\tr-tr
D:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\sv-se
// ... removed extra
```

Comment: "dir /A:D/S/B/O:-D | sort /R" errors out sort: input file "/R": The system cannot find the file specified in windows 10

Comment: @user2782522, are you sure you are executing this in a Windows Command Prompt window (`cmd.exe`)??

Comment: @user2782522 My example IS from a Windows 10 command prompt. `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1348]` ... I updated the example to show more of the output.